# Wp-Admin extremely slow!

Tags: wp-admin

I noticed my wp-admin became extremely slow so I installed a plugin called debug bar extender to get some more info and found this:

[image: http://glui.me/?i=mquiiute9joj3vp/2014-05-30_at_3.00_PM.png/]

Any idea what on earth could be causing such a slow down? This was taken loading `options-general.php` in wp-admin

Comment: Try updating... At login WordPress Autochecks for Updates, and your screenshot showed 19 available.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling or deleting all of your plugins and starting over again?

You could also try to download a plugin to speed it up like:

- WP Super Cache
- W3 Total Cache

you can just [search](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=cache) for some other ones yourself also.

Comment: Their is also Quick Cache (Speed Without Compromise).

Comment: Slowness/high CPU usage could Also be due to (but not limited to): - a poor or memory intensive theme - poor or memory intensive plugins - your server is slow (e.g., "process hang", overload, you get a lot of visitors, other problems, etc.).
Test your site at (free online testing): http://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html OR http://www.webpagetest.org/ 
Also, review these resources: - http://www.wptavern.com/determining-which-plugins-are-slowing-your-site-down http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization